# Is my Retrofit custom callback a suitable implementation?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, android-livedata, mutablelivedata

Here I am passing mutable livedata object as listener. It's worked but is this a correct implementation? Are there any hidden problems with this implementation or is there a better solution?

### BaseCallback.kt

```
abstract class BaseCallback<T> constructor(private val listener: MutableLiveData<*>) : Callback<T> {
   override fun onResponse(call: Call<T>, response: Response<T>) {
    when {
        response.code() == 401 -> {
        }
        response.isSuccessful -> {
            onSuccess(response.body())
        }
        else -> {
            val apiError = ErrorUtils.parseError(response)
            listener.value = ApiResult.Error(exception = apiError!!)
        }
    }
}

override fun onFailure(call: Call<T>, t: Throwable) {
    listener.value = ApiResult.Error(
        ApiError(message = t.message ?: "Oops Something Went Wrong!")
    )
}

abstract fun onSuccess(response: T?)
}
```

### Viewmodel

```
private val _deviceListResponse = MutableLiveData<ApiResult<List<Device>>>()
val deviceListResponse: LiveData<ApiResult<List<Device>>> = _deviceListResponse

deviceRepo.getDevices().enqueue(object : BaseCallback<List<Device>>(_deviceListResponse) {
        override fun onSuccess(response: List<Device>?) {
            val devices = response ?: ArrayList()
            _deviceListResponse.value = ApiResult.Success(devices)
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

No you shouldn't pass LiveData to Callback, BaseCallback should be independent, here is a simple sample:

```
fun <T> baseCallBack(onSuccess: (response: T?) -> Unit, onFailure: (apiResult: ApiResult) -> Unit): Callback<T> {
    return object : Callback<T> {
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<T>, t: Throwable) {

        }

        override fun onResponse(call: Call<T>, response: Response<T>) {
            if (response.isSuccessful) {
                onSuccess(response.body())
            } else {
                onFailure(ApiResult.Error {
                    ApiError(message = t.message ?: "Oops Something Went Wrong!")
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```